# How to get vim using anaconda as default python3?

Tags: python

I am using Manjaro/Arch Linux and I use vim from `sudo pacman -S vim` instead of build it from source

I want to run my `.py` files in vim by F5 but when I added these to `~/.vimrc`:

```
map <F5> :call CompileRunGcc()<CR>
    func! CompileRunGcc()
        exec "w"
if &filetype == 'c'
            exec "!g++ % -o %<"
            exec "!time ./%<"
elseif &filetype == 'cpp'
            exec "!g++ % -o %<"
            exec "!time ./%<"
elseif &filetype == 'java'
            exec "!javac %"
            exec "!time java %<"
elseif &filetype == 'sh'
            :!time bash %
elseif &filetype == 'python'
            exec "!time python %"
elseif &filetype == 'html'
            exec "!firefox % &"
elseif &filetype == 'go'
    "        exec "!go build %<"
            exec "!time go run %"
elseif &filetype == 'mkd'
            exec "!~/.vim/markdown.pl % > %.html &"
            exec "!firefox %.html &"
endif
    endfunc
```

it will show (originally in Chinese)

```
function CompileRunGcc --> error
In line 1:
E382: cannot write in，has been set as 'buftype'
when running .py files
```

I am using anaconda as my default python environment, and I installed them at `~/.anaconda`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I don’t think it’s related to your issue, but you don’t need all the exec’s; those are generally used when you need to build commands from strings. So you can simply use `write`, `!g++ % -o %<`, etc. And you may be interested in `:help :compiler` and `:help :make`.

Comment: As for your question, the error indicates that vim cannot write the file: can you give an example filename where this error happens? Have you checked permissions in that directory/for that file?

Comment: just a .py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filetype plugin on
map <F5> :call RunPython()<CR>
function! RunPython()
    exec "w"
    if &filetype == 'python'
        if search("@profile")
            exec "AsyncRun kernprof -l -v %"
        elseif search("set_trace()")
            exec "!~/.anaconda/bin/python %"
        else
            exec "AsyncRun -mode=term -pos=bottom ~/.anaconda/bin/python %"
        endif
    endif
endfunc
```

Now it works, Thanks to @D.Ben Knoble

Answer (score 0):

Now this work but it will throw `EOF Error` when meeting `input()`

```
map <F5> :call RunPython()<CR>
function! RunPython()
    exec "w"
    if &filetype == 'python'
            if search("@profile")
                    exec "AsyncRun kernprof -l -v %"
                    exec "copen"
                    exec "wincmd p"
             elseif search("set_trace()")
                     exec "!python3 %"
             else
                    exec "AsyncRun -raw python3 %"
                    exec "copen"
                    exec "wincmd p"
            endif
    endif
endfunc
```

Comment: Once again, not that it matters, you can write `AsyncRun ...` and `copen` directly, no `exec`/quotes necessary